# Book Identification: Noone house

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I remember reading a book, probably 10 years ago now at least, though the book itself may be older than that. It was about a girl who goes to live in a large house in the country (I don't recall why). She must have had adults there but I don't recall if they were relatives.

The whole story had a slightly creepy tone. There was a maze in the garden of the house and I think the climax involved a race around that maze. In the centre was something important - possible a golden statue? It may have turned into a person at the end.

She may possibly have had a boy friend, though I am not certain on that point.

I am fairly sure that the girl's surname was Noone and the house was also called Noone House/Hall or similar. At some point she realised that Noone was the same as No-one and somehow this was relevant (and also a little freaky from what I remember).

The book was probably aimed at 14 year olds upwards - though again I'm not sure.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Aside from a "creepy tone", what about it was science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: I believe it was fantasy, though I don't remember there being magic as such. I think it was probably more a magical setting and the creepiness could have come from possibly from the idea of a curse on the family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lead character seems to be the boy not the girl, but how about [Night Maze](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0749746025) by Annie Dalton?

It's from 2001 so about the right age.  As the title suggests, it involves a maze.  It takes place at a large house in the country, although it's called Owlcote, not Noone.  The lead character's surname is Noone though, and he has a female cousin whose name is also Noone.

Comment: I was so intrigued by the description that I bought a copy of the book.  Thanks for a good read!